# How to specify Kubernetes pod acquisition timeout in a Jenkins pipeline using Job DSL?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a seed job creating other jobs using the Job DSL plugin on Jenkins. Each created job is using Git to fetch and execute a pipeline. Pretty standard workflow from what I've found around on the internet.

The issue is that our Kubernetes cluster, or maybe our pod definitions, allow for all 80 cores to be assigned to a given pod to speed up CI jobs, so every now and then a queued job has to wait before their pod is made available. I had a job with 30 minutes timeout only "build" for 3 minutes before being cancelled because it waited for 25 minutes for the pod to become available.

Is there anyway to specify a global timeout including waiting for Kubernetes (let's say 1 hour, or 2 hours even to be on the safe side)? I've already migrated my 30 minute timeout to the inner building step, but the outermost timeout is still only applied after the pod is made available, it seems that the whole pipeline is processed on the pod.

Here is what my current pipeline looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

pipeline {

    options {
        timeout(time: 2, unit: 'HOURS')
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '60', daysToKeepStr: '14', artifactNumToKeepStr: '60', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '14'))
    }

    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yamlFile 'xyz.yaml'
            defaultContainer 'xyz
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                    dir('coverage_build') {
                        sh "./jenkins_scripts/coverage_build.sh"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            publishHTML target: [
                allowMissing: false,
                alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                keepAll: true,
                reportDir: './build_dir/coverage',
                reportFiles: 'index.html',
                reportName: 'LCov Report'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Effectively this is timing out after 30 minutes. But I wanted to make it resistant to delays on the pod acquisition.

Comment: Why do you use 2 timeouts? The 30min timeout overrides your 2hours one I think.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was hoping that the 2 hours timeout would start before the pod is provided, but that wasn't the case. The question is "Where to put this 2 hour timeout?"